# Declaring a Django signal inside a method

Tags: django

I'm trying to remove a file that I've created after it's been sent to the user:

```
def download_file(request, contents):

    f = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

    def test_signal(sender, **kwargs):
        print 'finished'
        os.remove(f.name)
    request_finished.connect(test_signal)

    f.write(contents)
    f.close()

    response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(open(f.name)), content_type='application/force-download')

    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str('file.txt')

    return response
```

Downloading the file works fine, but the signal won't get triggered.

What puzzles me is that it does work when I put test_signal() outside of the download_file(), i.e. declaring it above at the same level, but if I do that I can't access the name of the file to remove.

Why can't I use test_signal() when it's declared inside this method?

Comment: You can pass the name through `dispatch_uid` and in this case is a good way to use it, as it won't get called multiple times for the same file. Admittedly a bit hacky, but it will work for this specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the signal dispatcher uses weak references to the receiver functions, which are not counted as references by the garbage collector. As soon as your view function finishes, there are no more (strong) references to the signal receiver, and it gets garbage collected by Python soon afterwards (assuming CPython).

You need to tell the signal dispatcher to use strong references instead:

```
request_finished.connect(test_signal, weak=False)
```